# Does play store pre-launch report warnings delay the publication in the Beta release or in production?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I have recently uploaded the app to the Play-Store after months of building it and now play store delayed publish. So, after browsing through the console found "Pre-release report", so 4 some minor issues. So, thought that they are causing the delay, so updated the app those issues removed and got now only 1 issue, which is of the before issues, which is not at all an issue actually. Because of these things I have rolled same app to the production.

So, my question is does pre-launch report really delay the publication time, even the issues are not issues actually, because the bot is flagged the issue actually.

Comment: Hi, is it really true pre-launch report causing delay when publishing an app?

Comment: Izzuddiin nope it's not causing delay anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pre launch reports don't cause any delay...you are facing the delay which is currently being faced by all developers. Google has also mentioned the reason behind it that because of covid 19 pandemic they are taking more than usual review time. If it is first app for play store then it will take about 7 days or else less than 7 days. I recently published my 3rd app and it took 2 days but first one took 7 days. Similarly first app update took 2 days but 3rd apps update takes less than 1 hour may be I think now it is taking lesser time as now lockdowns have been taken off by govt. In some places.